# Need Help Tracking Down EXC_BAD_ACCESS on Function Entry on MacOS

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, debugging, exc-bad-access

I have a program that gets a KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE with EXC_BAD_ACCESS in a very strange place when running multithreaded and I haven't the faintest idea how to troubleshoot it further.  This is on MacOS 10.6 using GCC.

The very strange place that it gets this is when entering a function.  Not on the first line of the function, but the actual jump to the function GetMachineFactors():

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0xb00009ec
[Switching to process 28242]
0x00012592 in GetMachineFactors () at ../sysinfo/OSX.cpp:168
168 MachineFactors* GetMachineFactors()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00012592 in GetMachineFactors () at ../sysinfo/OSX.cpp:168
#1  0x000156d0 in CollectMachineFactorsThreadProc (parameter=0x200280) at Threads.cpp:341
#2  0x952f681d in _pthread_start ()
#3  0x952f66a2 in thread_start ()
(gdb)
```

If I run this non-threaded, it runs great, no issues:

```
#include "MachineFactors.h"

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    MachineFactors* factors = GetMachineFactors();
    std::string str = CreateJSONObject(factors);
    cout << str;
    delete factors;
    return 0;
}
```

If I run this in a pthread, I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS above.

```
THREAD_FUNCTION CollectMachineFactorsThreadProc( LPVOID parameter )
{
    Main* client = (Main*) parameter;
    if ( parameter == NULL )
    {
        ERRORLOG( "No data passed to machine identification thread.  Aborting." );
        return 0;
    }
    MachineFactors* mfactors = GetMachineFactors(); // This is where it dies.
    // If I don't call GetMachineFactors and do something like mfactors =
    // new MachineFactors(); everything is good and the threads communicate and exit
    // normally.
    if (mfactors == NULL)
    {
        ERRORLOG("Failed to collect machine identification: GetMachineFactors returned NULL." << endl)
        return 0;
    }
    client->machineFactors = CreateJSONObject(mfactors);
    delete mfactors;
    EVENT_RAISE(client->machineFactorsEvent);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an excerpt from the GetMachineFactors() code:

```
MachineFactors* GetMachineFactors() // Dies on this line in multi-threaded.
{
    // printf( "Getting machine factors.\n"); // Tried with and without this, never prints.
    factors = new MachineFactors();
    factors->OSName = "MacOS";
    factors->Manufacturer = "Apple";
    ///…
    // gather various machine metrics here.
    //…
    return factors;
}
```

For reference, I am using a socketpair to wait on the thread to complete:

```
// From the header file I use for cross-platform defines (this runs on OSX, Windows, and Linux.
struct _waitt
{
  int fds[2];
};
#define THREAD_FUNCTION void*
#define THREAD_REFERENCE pthread_t
#define MUTEX_REFERENCE pthread_mutex_t*
#define MUTEX_LOCK(m) pthread_mutex_lock(m)
#define MUTEX_UNLOCK pthread_mutex_unlock
#define EVENT_REFERENCE struct _waitt
#define EVENT_WAIT(m) do { char lc; if (read(m.fds[0], &lc, 1)) {} } while (0)
#define EVENT_RAISE(m) do { char lc = 'j'; if (write(m.fds[1], &lc, 1)) {} } while (0)
#define EVENT_NULL(m) do { m.fds[0] = -1; m.fds[1] = -1; } while (0)
```

Here is the code where I launch the thread.

```
void Main::CollectMachineFactors()
{
#ifdef WIN32
    machineFactorsThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, CollectMachineFactorsThreadProc, this, 0, 0);
    if ( machineFactorsThread == NULL )
    {
        ERRORLOG( "Could not create thread for machine id: " << ERROR_NO << endl )
    }
#else
    int retval = pthread_create(&machineFactorsThread, NULL, CollectMachineFactorsThreadProc, this);
    if (retval)
    {
        ERRORLOG( "Return code from machine id pthread_create() is " << retval << endl )
    }
#endif
}
```

Here's the simple failure case of running this multithreaded.  It always fails for this code with the stack trace above:

```
CollectMachineFactors();
EVENT_WAIT(machineFactorsEvent);
cout << machineFactors;
return 0;
```

At first I suspected a library problem.  Here's my makefile:

```
# Main executable file
PROGRAM = sysinfo
# Object files
OBJECTS = Version.h Main.o Protocol.o Socket.o SSLConnection.o Stats.o TimeElapsed.o Formatter.o OSX.o Threads.o
# Include directories
INCLUDE = -Itaocrypt/include -IyaSSL/taocrypt/mySTL -IyaSSL/include -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
# Library settings
STATICLIBS = libtaocrypt.a libyassl.a -Wl,-rpath,. -ldl -lpthread -lz -lexpat
# Compile settings
RELCXX = g++ -g -ggdb -DDEBUG -Wall $(INCLUDE)

.SUFFIXES:      .o .cpp

.cpp.o :
        $(RELCXX) -c -Wall $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $<

all:    $(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM):     $(OBJECTS)
        $(RELCXX) -o $(PROGRAM) $(OBJECTS) $(STATICLIBS)

clean: 
    rm -f *.o $(PROGRAM)
```

I can't for the life of me see anything particularly odd or dangerous and I'm not sure where to look.  The same threaded process works fine on any Linux machine I have tried.  Any suggestions?  Any tools I should try?

I can add more info if it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, and I can't explain why, that a fork() call combined with a socketpair() as the IPC mechanism was the workaround to get things going as intended.

I wish I knew why it was failing in the first place (*headscratch*) but that approach seems to have been a good workaround.

It almost seemed like the kind of "build out of whack" problem that could be caused by failing to run a 'make clean' after changing header files, but that wasn't the case here.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a problem with your Windows code, but not the OSX code that's crashing on you.

It seems that you're not posting the actual code for `GetMachineFactors`, since the variable `factors` is not declared. But regarding debugging, you should not take the non-appearance of `printf` output as conclusive that that statement hasn't been executed. Use debugger facilities such as setting a breakpoint, using special debugger trace output, so on (not sure what gdb handles, it's a very primitive debugger, but perhaps Apple has better tools?).

For Windows, you should use the run time library's thread creation instead of Windows API `CreateThread`. That's because with `CreateThread` the runtime lib isn't informed. E.g, a `new` expression or other call that uses the runtime lib might fail.

Sorry I can't help more.

I think it could perhaps have something to do with the `GetMachineFactors` code that you haven't shown?

Comment: Thank you for trying, but it turned out to be one of those 'weird inexplicable problems' that required a fork() to behave right.